# Why cannot I send multiple WWW-authenticate header

Tags: php, apache, nginx

I am sending multiple WWW-authenticate headers with php: first Negotiate and second NTLM, but browsers receive only the latter one. The front-end web server is Nginx. The back-end web server is Apache, that serves PHP-scripts. What should I do to send both headers?

Comment: You can only send one. However, you should be able to send them as a comma separated list.

Comment: _The front-end web server is Nginx_ Just for frontend, why would you need Nginx?

Comment: IIS can send 2 headers. The 2-server scheme is preinstalled in the product distro.

Comment: I tried to send multiple headers with a comma separated list as WWW-authenticate: Negotiate, WWW-authenticate: NTLM and WWW-authenticate: Negotiate, NTLM, but the result was that the latter header was actually sent.

Answer (score 1):

Got it solved. I should have set the second argument to the header function as false. header('WWW-authenticate: NTLM',false);